# Как соединить выделенный IP с сервисом Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

Установил тестовый пример на Kubernetes (minikube), который выдает в браузере сайт на WordPress. Пример взят с [Example: Deploying WordPress and MySQL with Persistent Volumes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateful-application/mysql-wordpress-persistent-volume/).
Подскажите, как мне связать сервис отвечающий за отображение сайта с выделенным IP адресом? Чтобы введя выделенный IP адрес я мог попасть на сайт размещенный у меня в кластере Kubernetes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вы используете minikube, то такая возможность отсутствует.

Но есть обходные пути...

Когда используется VirtualBox как hypervisor вы можете использовать VirtualBox NAT порты для переадресации, чтобы открыть доступ к службам открытым через NodePorts извне.

Как-то так... (ограниченный диапазон, отображающий весь диапазон NodePort по умолчанию, равный 30000-32767).

Устанавливаем правила переадресации:

```
for port in {30000..30100}; do VBoxManage controlvm minikube natpf1 "NodePort$port,tcp,,$port,,$port"; done
```

Вы можете комбинировать с обратным SSH-туннелем с VPS, чтобы все могли иметь временный доступ из интернета:

```
R_ARGS=$(for port in {30000..30100}; do echo -n "-R $port:localhost:$port "; done)
autossh -M 0 -q -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o ExitOnForwardFailure=yes -o ServerAliveInterval=5 -o ServerAliveCountMax=3 user@examplevps.com -N $R_ARGS
```

Чтобы удалить правила переадресации портов VirtualBox выполните следующую команду:

```
for port in {30000..30100}; do VBoxManage controlvm minikube natpf1 delete "NodePort$port"; done
```

Вот ссылки на оригинальные статьи:

https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/877

https://cwienczek.com/reaching-minikube-from-your-machines-public-ip-aka-network-bridge/

Answer (score 0):

вариант для бариметал .создайте алиас на интерфейс ноды с тем ip что вам нужен(х.х.х.х.х), а в описании сервиса используйте

```
spec:
  externalIPs:
  - х.х.х.х
```